# import distribution group members into security group via PowerShell

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

Can anyone give me some guidance on what PowerShell command I can use to import all the members of a distribution group in Active Directory into a security group?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any specific problem you encounter when starting your approach of getting each of the two data sets at first?

Comment: thanks for your reply I got stuck at get-adgroupmember -identity "nameofgroup" not sure what command to use to import the distribution group members into the security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use this (use your group names for "distributiongroup" and "securitygroup"):

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity distributiongroup | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity securitygroup -Members $_ }
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

To add to stephanb's answer, if you have nested groups under the distribution group you are attempting to copy from, you will need to add the -recursive parameter in order to pull in the users from those sub-groups.

Here is an example that worked for me:

`Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'securitygroup' -Members (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'distributiongroup' -Recursive)`